# Display correctly using metabox.io

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I'm struggling to find the proper way to display the date at the front end of my theme. I am using metabox.io for custom fields in my custom post type.

The basic way to echo is this:
    echo rwmb_meta( 'ls_course-date-1');
ls_course-date-1 being my field id.

the documentation to display a pretty date is [here](https://metabox.io/docs/display-date-in-one-format-and-save-in-another-format/) but I don't know how I am meant to implement it. It refers to further documentation [here](https://metabox.io/docs/filters/#section-rwmb_field_id_value)but again, I don't know how to implement. My php level is intermediate at best and whilst I've had no problem creating all of the arrays and returning most of them, I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was much simpler than I thought.

```
            $date_meta = rwmb_meta( 'ls_course-date-3'); 
            echo date('jS F, o  ', strtotime($date_meta));
```